# Trouble with Mail Merge IF field and VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I have a very simple mail merge that is connected to an SQL server database

The mail merge has two fields on it, one is

```
{MERGEFIELD Dealer_Name}
```

the other is the following IF field

```
{IF {MERGEFIELD Dealer_Name}="Joe" "1" "0"}
```

However the IF field does not execute.  The Dealer_Name merge field does execute and displays each dealer name or each page but the IF field just displays as `Dealer_Name}=`

Also is it possible to write a VBA function or procedure and then add it to the word mail merge document as a field or merge button or something else.

For example let say I have the following VBA procedure

```
Public Sub PrintSomeText  
  Selection.TypeText("Hello World")
End Sub
```

Could I add this to the mail merge document as a macro or something so that it prints out "Hello World" on each page in the locate that it was placed onto the document?

Comment: The `If` one, how was it entered? Did you press Ctrl+F9 when you entered it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the IF field code working, not sure how, it just started working.

Also I found that you can use VBA code in Word mail merge documents by using the DOCVARIABLE or REF field codes.

For anyone else who has this problem:

Add a document variable like this:

```
{DOCVARIABLE MyVariable}
```

or a bookmark reference like this:

```
{REF MyBookmarkReference}
```

Then in VBA (Alt+F11) do the following:

In Project (Project name), e.g. Project(MailMergeDemo)
Under "Microsoft Word Objects"
Double click "ThisDocument"

and enter the following code

```
Dim WithEvents app As Application

Private Sub Document_Close()
  Set app = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Document_Open()
  Set app = Application
End Sub
```

Choose the app object from the drop down and then choose the app_MailMergeBeforeRecordMerge event and enter the following code:

```
Private Sub app_MailMergeBeforeRecordMerge(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As Boolean)
  Doc.Variables("MyVariable").Value = Doc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields(SomeFieldName).Value

  Doc.Bookmarks("MyBookmarkReference").Range.Text = "this is a test"

  Doc.Fields.Update
End Sub
```

You will need to close and reopen the document to hook the application object.

Please refer to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/285333 for more information.